# Spotfire can i input a column through ironpython script?

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

I understand that we can use `dataFunction.Inputs.SetInput(inputs,"String(\"HelloWorld\")")` to set a string to my input parameter. Is there any way I can give an entire column instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. I found the answer. It can be done using `dataFunction.Inputs.SetInput(inputs,"[DataTable name].[Column name]")`

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider marking it as the answer!

Comment: @MarkP. I cannot mark this as the answer as I am the one who asked the question and answered. Or is there a way I can mark it answered?